# What are secondary resources?

Tags: environmental-protection, resources

> The Indian Resource Panel shall prepare a strategic roadmap for **utilisation of secondary resources for meeting the developmental needs.** India is the first country to constitute a National Resource Panel.

An extract from a book am reading on Environment whose author is not internationally known but I’ll still mention his name, Shankar. 
The author has it mentioned as a Do You Know.

I ran a google search but couldn’t find any explanation to it.

Comment: is it possible for you to expand your question to give some more context and background for your question.

Comment: @trondhansen Hi. I have now mentioned the full context as the author has it in the book. It is mentioned under the Do You Know section and that’s all there is to it.

Comment: As @trondhansen has mentioned, the context of either the statement or the text would be useful. Secondary resources could simply mean alternate or other resources. In a different context, primary resources are considered to be resources of the earth, such as minerals, oil, natural gas, forests, water, etc. Secondary resources can include semi processed primary resources & tertiary resources can mean fully processed resources. For example, a primary resource would be iron ore or trees in a forest. Secondary resources would be pig iron or paper pulp. Tertiary resources would be steel or paper.

Comment: let me put it  like this,what type of development is it,is it for building roads,or is it for expanding eg a power grid where you have a primary power source and there is a need for a secondary backup source(where i live the primary power source is hydro power and the secondary source is wind power). what type of development is it?

Comment: @trondhansen Okay totally unrelated. I am reading a chapter on “Environmental Pollution” and the text quoted above as the question appeared in the “Do You Know” segment that’s sprinkled throughout the book. I looked up online what does he mean by “secondary resources” but Google would show me search for “primary and secondary sources” thereby leaving me confused as to what actually is meant by secondary resources and for what kind of development. Nothing is specified in the text from the book.

Comment: Based on your additional comments so far, primary resources could possibly be main or high quality resources. Secondary resources would then be alternate or lower quality resources that could be utilized when the quality primary ones have been exhausted. A primary high quality resource might be a forest of oak trees or high quality water; a secondary resource might then be a forest of beech trees, or slightly saline or contaminated water.

Answer (score 1):

lets say a water company do deliver water to a city but as the city expands the water source are no longer able to keep up with the demand so the water company have to drill a new well,This is now an alternative source for water the company will still use the primary source for water but will need to use the secondary source in periods of high water demand.

The same is true for building materials if the primary supplier are not able to deliver what you need,You have to get it from an alternative source.

And as i mention in my comment,my primary supplier of electric power is hydro power,So this is the primary source of power for me and if i use more power than they can produce the rest must be supplied from an alternative source,Here this will be wind power or import from other sources.

In denmark the primary source for electric power is wind and the secondary sources is hydro power from norway or coal power from the continental europe.

the comment from fred is an answer to this question too